# SQL Insert using OpenXML resulting in null data

Tags: sql, openxml

I am attempting to put data into a @table but for some reason I keep getting all my rows with null values.  Im getting the null rows even without the insert portion.  Everything seems like it should function.  Anything glaring that Im missing?

```
DECLARE       @AuthData_XML VARCHAR(max)

set @AuthData_XML = '
<AuthData>
<LOC>
   <Loc_ID>1</Loc_ID>
   <LocName>DD - Residential IP - Evaluation - Psychiatric</LocName>
   <Proccode></Proccode>
   <Proc_ID>7281</Proc_ID>
   <Selected>false</Selected>
   <DefaultUnits>0</DefaultUnits>
   <Func_Area>5319</Func_Area>
   <Serv_ID>0</Serv_ID>
   <Patient_ID>1222</Patient_ID>
</LOC>
<LOC>
       <Loc_ID>22</Loc_ID>
       <LocName>MH - Outpatient - Group Therapy</LocName>
       <Proccode>90853</Proccode>
       <Proc_ID>6697</Proc_ID>
       <Selected>false</Selected>
       <DefaultUnits>0</DefaultUnits>
       <Func_Area>0</Func_Area>
       <Serv_ID>0</Serv_ID>
       <Patient_ID>1222</Patient_ID>
</LOC>
<LOC>
       <Loc_ID>26</Loc_ID>
       <LocName>MH - Outpatient - Individual Therapy - 30min</LocName>
       <Proccode>90804</Proccode>
       <Proc_ID>7381</Proc_ID>
       <Selected>false</Selected>
       <DefaultUnits>0</DefaultUnits>
       <Func_Area>0</Func_Area>
       <Serv_ID>0</Serv_ID>
       <Patient_ID>1222</Patient_ID>
</LOC>
<LOC>
       <Loc_ID>94</Loc_ID>
       <LocName>SA - Inpatient - Detoxification</LocName>
       <Proccode>H0009</Proccode>
       <Proc_ID>7399</Proc_ID>
       <Selected>false</Selected>
       <DefaultUnits>0</DefaultUnits>
       <Func_Area>0</Func_Area>
       <Serv_ID>0</Serv_ID>
       <Patient_ID>1222</Patient_ID>
</LOC>
<LOC>
       <Loc_ID>47</Loc_ID>
       <LocName>MH - Medical-Surgical - Consult - Follow-up</LocName>
       <Proccode>99232</Proccode>
       <Proc_ID>7283</Proc_ID>
       <Selected>false</Selected>
       <DefaultUnits>0</DefaultUnits>
       <Func_Area>0</Func_Area>
       <Serv_ID>0</Serv_ID>
       <Patient_ID>1222</Patient_ID>
</LOC>
</AuthData>'

DECLARE @iDoc int
DECLARE @ServiceRequestData TABLE (Loc_ID int, LocName varchar(200), Proccode varchar(10), Proc_ID int, Selected int, DefaultUnits int, Func_Area int, Serv_ID int, Patient_ID int)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @iDoc OUTPUT, @AuthData_XML
       INSERT INTO @ServiceRequestData
              SELECT        Loc_ID,
                     LocName,
                     Proccode,
                     Proc_ID,
                     Selected,
                     DefaultUnits,
                     Func_Area,
                     Serv_ID,
                     Patient_ID
              FROM Openxml(@iDoc, '/AuthData/LOC', 9) WITH (Loc_ID int, LocName varchar(200), Proccode varchar(10), Proc_ID int, Selected int, DefaultUnits int, Func_Area int, Serv_ID int, Patient_ID int)
```

As a result, my data isn't going into the table.  All examples Ive seen so far are pretty close to what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up changing from openxml to using xquery.  I changed the var type to XML and was able to use the below query to get the data I was expected.

```
INSERT INTO @ServiceRequestData
SELECT  IdNode.value('(Loc_ID)[1]','int') AS Loc_ID,
    IdNode.value('(LocName)[1]','varchar(200)') AS LocName, 
    IdNode.value('(Proccode)[1]','varchar(10)') AS Proccode, 
    IdNode.value('(Proc_ID)[1]','int') AS Proc_ID, 
    IdNode.value('(Selected)[1]','bit') AS Selected, 
    IdNode.value('(DefaultUnits)[1]','int') AS DefaultUnits, 
    IdNode.value('(Func_Area)[1]','int') AS Func_Area, 
    IdNode.value('(Serv_ID)[1]','int') AS Serv_ID, 
    IdNode.value('(Patient_ID)[1]','int') AS Patient_ID
FROM @AuthData_XML.nodes('/AuthData/LOC') AS idTbl(IdNode)
```